# Bind DataTrigger to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datatrigger

Is it possable to bind datatrigger to dependencyproperty of the element, w/o using "ElementName"?

I have:

```
    <controls:LanguageTextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                            Text="{Binding LanguagesNames.Language1}">
                    <controls:LanguageTextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="controls:LanguageTextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LanguagesNames.Language1}"></DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </controls:LanguageTextBlock.Style>
                </controls:LanguageTextBlock>
```

so I want something like that:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{ThisElement Text}"></DataTrigger>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `DataTrigger`

```
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="...">
    <!-- ... -->
</Trigger>
```